# Pyrogram, problem [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] on Linux

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I wrote a simple script on python to copy messages in one chat to the other. The destination chat is a chat with a telegram bot.
It works perfectly on my computer, but I wanted it to work on my Raspberry Pi (not to keep my Windows computer ON). When I started the script on Raspberry it started to place the error:

> Telegram says: [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] - The peer id being used is invalid or not known yet. Make sure you meet the peer before interacting with it
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/resolve_peer.py", line 60, in resolve_peer
> return await self.storage.get_peer_by_id(peer_id)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyrogram/storage/sqlite_storage.py", line 148, in get_peer_by_id
> raise KeyError(f"ID not found: {peer_id}")
> KeyError: 'ID not found: 1321800342'

So I checked all didgets, everything is right, checked the chat id again. I have an idia, that the problem is that exactly that device (Raspberry Pi) didn't write to that bot itself. But maybe I am wrong.
Did anyone has the same issue? Do you have any idias how to solve it?
Thanks a lot.

```
 from pyrogram import Client, filters

# Target chat. Can also be a list of multiple chat ids/usernames
TARGET = -730374088

app = Client("my_account")


# Filter in only new_chat_members updates generated in TARGET chat
@app.on_message(filters.chat(TARGET) & filters.text)
async def welcome(client, message):
    await app.send_message(1321800342, message.text)


app.run()  # Automatically start() and idle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new session on your Pi likely hasn't seen the chat/channel, and thus doesn't know what to associate the ID to. Make sure the new session receives any kind of update from the chat/channel and read Pyrogram's FAQ section on the error.

Comment: I don't know why, but it worked when i changed chat id to username of the bot. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @ИльяЛян The Username can be resolved and an ID retrieved from it. IDs cannot be retrieved without having met them before. That's why ID fails, but Username works.

Answer (score 0):

Worked well when I changed chat id to the bot's username.